# Javascript Date constructor removes a day from passed value and generates a date of day before

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, datetime, mongoose

I am passing this data to a function:

```
[
  {
    "date": "07/12/2021",
  },
  {
    "date": "07/11/2021",
  },
  {
    "date": "07/10/2021",
  },
  {
    "date": "07/09/2021",
  },
  {
    "date": "07/08/2021",
  },
  {
    "date": "07/07/2021",
  }
   ]
```

And I am generating dates using the date field.
The problem each day generated is for the day before.
For example, for this date "07/07/2021" it generates `2021-07-06T23:00:00.000Z`:

Here's the result for the whole passed data:

> ~ file: analyticsServices.js ~ line 1242 ~ date 07/12/2021
>
> ~ file: analyticsServices.js ~ line 1238 ~ new Date(date)
> 2021-07-11T23:00:00.000Z
>
> ~ file: analyticsServices.js ~ line 1242 ~ date 07/11/2021
>
> ~ file: analyticsServices.js ~ line 1238 ~ new Date(date)
> 2021-07-10T23:00:00.000Z
>
> ~ file: analyticsServices.js ~ line 1242 ~ date 07/10/2021
>
> ~ file: analyticsServices.js ~ line 1238 ~ new Date(date)
> 2021-07-09T23:00:00.000Z
>
> ~ file: analyticsServices.js ~ line 1242 ~ date 07/09/2021
>
> ~ file: analyticsServices.js ~ line 1238 ~ new Date(date)
> 2021-07-08T23:00:00.000Z
>
> ~ file: analyticsServices.js ~ line 1242 ~ date 07/08/2021
>
> ~ file: analyticsServices.js ~ line 1238 ~ new Date(date)
> 2021-07-07T23:00:00.000Z
>
> ~ file: analyticsServices.js ~ line 1242 ~ date 07/07/2021
>
> ~ file: analyticsServices.js ~ line 1238 ~ new Date(date)
> 2021-07-06T23:00:00.000Z

I had a small doubt, that it's just a notation convention (to write one day lower). But, when I retrieve these dates from the mongodb database and I convert them back to strings, the result is still the same. All the dates are one day behind the data I submitted in the first place.

Any idea what's going-on?

Comment: Looks like different timezones

Comment: What does timezone have to do with the Date constructor generating a date with a day lower than the value passed to it?

Comment: If you pass in a date string like `"07/07/2021"`, which has no timezone information and no timestamp, the browser is going to assume it's intended to be at 00:00 in your local timezone and it looks like in your case that's +01:00, which results in a date that is "2021-07-07T00:00:00.000+0100", which is the same as "2021-07-06T23:00:00.000Z" (UTC)

Comment: @AG_HIHI BTW, you shouldn't need to think about the timezone as long as you're consistent. If you invoke `.getDate()` or `.getMonth()` on your date object you'll get the numbers you expect because those methods also assume local timezone.

Comment: Use [*toDateString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString) and you'll see the date you expect (provided you think "07/12/2021" is 12 July and not 7 December).